# Captiulo 1, Kotlin in Action, Expecting a top level declaration [Iniciante]

Tags: kotlin

Estou aprendendo Kotlin, não consigo entender porque o problema "Expecting a top level declaration".
O resultado que eu pretendia era que apontasse Bob como o mais velho

```
data class Person(val name: String,
val age: Int? = null)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val persons = listOf(Person("Alice"),
                        Person("Bob", age = 29))
val oldest = persons.maxBy { it.age ?: 0 } }

println("The oldest is: $oldest")
```

Copiei igualzinho ao livro
mas fica retornando isso abaixo

Expecting a top level declaration
Expecting a top level declaration
Expecting a top level declaration
Expecting a top level declaration
Expecting a top level declaration
Expecting a top level declaration
Expecting a top level declaration
Expecting a top level declaration

Comment: seu println está fora da função main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função println ficou fora da função main, no caso a chave de fechamento "}" veio antes.

Testei aqui no Intellij e o código funciona.

Como pode perceber a única mudança que fiz nesse código, foi retirar o parâmetro da função "main" para rodar no Intellij.

```
package testes

data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int? = null)

fun main() {
    val persons = listOf(Person("Alice"), Person("Bob", age = 29))
    val oldest = persons.maxBy { it.age ?: 0 }

    println("The oldest is: $oldest")
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]